# When starting the game program, it writes the following text when moving to a new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

With my code, he writes: Object reference not set to an instance of an object `achscript.Start ()`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class achscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int money;
    public int total_money;
    [SerializeField] Button firstAch;
    [SerializeField] bool isFirst;
    // button кнопка. bool получено или нет
    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        isFirst = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirst") == 1 ? true : false;

        if (total_money >= 10 && !isFirst)
        {
            firstAch.interactable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            firstAch.interactable = false;
            StartCoroutine(IdleFarm());
        }
    }

    public void GetFirst()
    {
        int money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        money += 10;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
        isFirst = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isFirst", isFirst ? 1 : 0);
    }

    IEnumerator IdleFarm()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //для нецелого (1.5f)
        money++;
        Debug.Log(money);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money); //страка "money", значение money (это сохраниение баланса)
        StartCoroutine(IdleFarm());
    }

    public void ToMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I tried to look for a solution on the Internet. I didn't find anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: welcome.. However, please dont just come throw code and a half worded error.    The error is right, whichever line of code it points to, its right. So, look at that line, look at all the things on it, find out which one is empty, work out why its empty - eg what you forgot, fix it.  most lines only usually have at most 4 things it could apply to, you havent even shared which line it is.

Comment: The only object that can be giving you are null reference is firstAch.  Where are you calling the constructor with NEW : firstArch = new Button()

Comment: well And then how can you make sure that it does not give out an error. I just can't understand it. I haven't tried for a long time. It's always a mistake. I need him to check it out. Does the player have an achievement? If there is, then you can click on the button. If not. You can't do that

Comment: @jdweng Presumably, this field is supposed to be assigned in the inspector.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How is that script used? Do you have something assigned to the `firstAch` field there? You have to tell your script _which_ button to disable, after all.

Comment: Yes, I found what the problem was. I did not specify the button in the input field

Answer (score 1):

Did you add scene in build setting?

SceneManager.LoadScene(0) need add Scene

Comment: Yes, I found what the problem was. I did not specify the button in the input field

Comment: This answer should be a comment to the question.